# Newly added SSTF i/o scheduler not working

Tags: c, linux-kernel, operating-system

I want SSTF I/O scheduler in my linux. I recompiled my kernel successfully and took the code from : https://github.com/davidmerrick/Classes/blob/master/CS411/project2/code/sstf-iosched.c
Steps I performed :

1. I copied the file to block layer directory.
2. Modified Kconfig.iosched :

   ```
   config IOSCHED_SSTF
   bool
   default y
   ---help---
      A no-op scheduler that really does nothing - SSTF.
   .
   .
   ```
3. Modified Makefile :

   ```
   obj-$(CONFIG_IOSCHED_SSTF) += sstf-iosched.o
   ```

Then I recompiled the kernel which was successful with one or two warnings. The problem is though I can see my scheduler but I can't select it. I used the following command to change the scheduler.

```
    echo "sstf" > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
```

Please help. Am I missing something ? I am a novice in OS.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You may find some advice also in the "Unix & Linux" forum. There's about ~1000 questions concerned with kernel compilation, some of them may be relevant to your problem, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=compile+kernel and also [Unix & Linux: Help Center > Asking > What topics can I ask about here?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)